# How can I hang a skateboard deck on the wall?

Tags: walls

I have a Skateboard deck and I'd like to hang it on the wall. Analog to hanging a frame on the wall.

I've thinking about it but I have no idea on how to do it. Firstly I was thinking to suspend it, but I think it's not elegant enough.
If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: I've found one solution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JtWbTmFGIY&feature=related

Answer (score 1):

Are the holes for the truck already drilled? If so, a long enough screw with a block of wood used as a spacer to clear the kicktail(s) would let you mount it almost invisibly. (I'm assuming you want to show off the underside of the deck)

Comment: What you mean is fixing my deck with the usual truck screw but fixed on block of wood (fixed on the wall)?